# Multiprocessing pool does not wait for job completion

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

def job(i):
    print('I am job', i)
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
    for i in range(2):
        pool.apply_async(job, args=(i,))
pool.join()
```

Shouldn't this wait forever for the two child processes to finish, which will never happen? Instead the parent process exits immediately.

This seems to be some consequence of using the context manager syntax; the following works:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
for i in range(2):
    pool.apply_async(job, args=(i,))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: The context `__exit__` calls `terminate` to stop work immediately.

Comment: Yep, I see this in the docs now. Thanks. I assumed it would `join()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your original `pool.join()` is called outside of the `with ... as` context:

```
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
    for i in range(2):
        pool.apply_async(job, args=(i,))
pool.join()   # <-- indent is wrong
```

The correct version is:

```
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
    for i in range(2):
        pool.apply_async(job, args=(i,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```